# Image saving in android mobile for setting wallpaper in titanium

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, wallpaper

I am working in titanium. I am facing an issue i.e. can I save an image taken by camera,Gallery,PhotoAlbum or from a feed of twitter feeds for setting as wallpaper in android device using titanium as a platform.
I really need help cause i m stuck.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanx in advance.

PS: I have done this in iPhone(ios).
My working Code for ios is :

```
button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
var blob=largeImage.toImage();
Titanium.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(blob);       
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists setasystemwallpaper method in api docs for setting images as wallpaper in android

[TI.Media.Android.SetasSystemWallpaper](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.Android)

Comment: use like Titanium.Media.Android.setSystemWallpaper( blob,true );    and try to test on actual device